# Passing around function including its context in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is something I don't understand in javascript and broke down a sample problem to an essential case:

```
    a = function () {
      this.b = 5;
    }

    a.prototype.c = function () {
      alert(this.b);
    }

    var d = new a();
    var e = d.c; // how do I save a ref to the method including the context (object)??

    d.c(); // 5 -> ok
    e();   // undefined -> wtf??
```

So why is the function being called without its context in the last example? And how can I call it with the context?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d.c` is like an unbound instance method. You can use `Function.prototype.bind` to create a new function that's bound to `d` (the first argument to `.bind` is the `this` argument):

```
var e = d.c.bind(d);
```

Or call `e` with `d` as the `this` argument:

```
e.call(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the method using the object to get the context right. So:

```
var e = function() { return d.c(); };
```

In newer browsers you can use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to do the same:

```
var e = d.c.bind(d);
```

In jQuery for example there is the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that you can use also in older browsers:

```
var e = $.proxy(d.c, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about resolving the `this` value. This is resolved in the following way:

```
myObject.something();//this in something is myObject
window.something();//this is window
button.onClick=function();//this when button is clicked is button
```

How to solve it is already given, it's a common pitfall with passing callbacks like in the following example using setTimeout

```
var test = function () {
  var me = this;// set reference to this
  this.sayAgain=function(){
     console.log("Hi, I am "+me.toString());
  }
}
test.prototype.toString=function(){
   return "test";
}

test.prototype.say = function () {
  console.log("Hi, I am "+this.toString());
}

var t = new test();
setTimeout(t.say,50);//=window passing functon without ref to this
setTimeout(function(){
  t.say();
},150);//=test passing ref with function
setTimeout(t.sayAgain,200);//=test using me as the saved this context
```

The second timeout passes a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to setTimeout, if you're planning to pass the say callback hundreds of times but only create a couple of test object instances then the implementation of the last one (sayAgain) would perform slightly better.

This because you create a closure when you create the test instance but not when passing sayAgain as a callback, if you create many test instances and would not pass `say` that many times then remove this.me and this.sayAgain from the function body and pass `say` as a closure.

You can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) but it's not supported in IE < 8 and I am not sure if it'll create a closure as in my example using `t.say`.