# How to ensure correct "this" with Promise.promisify?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am trying to refactory my nodejs server using promises with Bluebird library, but I am stuck in a simple problem.

After to get the users from my db, I want to list all notification class associated with this user:

Bad Way (working...)

```
adapter.getUsers(function(users){
    users.rows.forEach(function(item){
        user = item.username;
        adapter.getNotifications(user, function(notificationList){
            console.log(notificationList);
        })
    });
});
```

Elegant Tentative Way  (not working...)

```
var getNotifications = Promise.promisify(adapter.getNotifications);
adapter.getUsers().then(function(users) {
    users.rows.forEach(function(item){
        var dbUser = "sigalei/" + item.value.name;
        console.log(dbUser);
        return getNotifications(dbUser);
    });
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    console.log("NOTIFICATIONLIST");
});
```

However when I execute this code I get this error inside my getNotification method:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'nano' of undefined
>      at Adapter.getNotifications (/Users/DaniloOliveira/Workspace/sigalei-api/api/tools/couchdb-adapter.js:387:30)
>       at tryCatcher (/Users/DaniloOliveira/Workspace/sigalei-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)

## EDIT


After the user2864740`s precious comments, I noticed that the error is related with some scope problem. So, why after to use promisify method, the method dont getNotifications recognize the "this" env variable?

```
var Adapter = module.exports = function(config) {
    this.nano = require('nano')({
        url: url,
        request_defaults: config.request_defaults
    });
};

Adapter.prototype.getNotifications = function(userDb, done) {

    var that = this;
    console.log(that);
    var userDbInstance = that.nano.use(userDb);
    userDbInstance.view('_notificacao', 'lista',
      {start_key: "[false]", end_key: "[false,{}]"},
      function(err, body) {
        if(err){ done(err); }
        done(body);
    });

};
```

Comment: Hey, the error is generated inside the getNotifications method that is being  "promisify".

Comment: @user2864740 Again, I edited the question, I think that the problem is related with scope variables...

Comment: Try `.call()`ing it with the `adapter`as the `this`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the very common [problem of calling "unbound" methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17517770/1048572).
You can pass the context as an option to [`Promise.promisify`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) to have it bound:

```
var getNotifications = Promise.promisify(adapter.getNotifications, {context: adapter});
```

Alternatively, you'd need to `.bind()` the method, or call the new `getNotifications` function on the `adapter` (using `.call()`). You might also consider using `Promise.promisifyAll(adapater)` and then just calling `adapter.getNotificationsAsync(…)`.

Notice that this still doesn't work. You cannot simply create promises in a loop - you need to await them explicitly and return a promise from the `then` callback, otherwise just the `undefined` value you returned will be passed to the next callback immediately.

```
adapter.getUsers().then(function(users) {
    return Promise.all(users.rows.map(function(item){
        var dbUser = "sigalei/" + item.value.name;
        console.log(dbUser);
        return getNotifications(dbUser);
    }));
}).then(function(results) {
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
        console.log("result:", results[i]);
});
```

Instead of `Promise.all(users.rows.map(…))`, in Bluebird you can also use `Promise.map(users.rows, …)`.

Comment: You are correct, thank you for your detailed explanation for this question and the "unbound" methods.

Comment: In Bluebird 3.4.6 context is bound like this: 
`Promise.promisify(adapter.getNotifications, {context: adapter});`

Answer (score 2):

What about simply

```
var getNotifications = Promise.promisify(adapter.getNotifications.bind(adapter));
```

or possibly

```
var getNotifications = Promise.promisify(function () {
    return adapter.getNotifications.apply(adapter, arguments);
});
```

?

I'm not sure I understand your problem well, but this should make sure `this` is bound and not `undefined` when you do `return getNotifications(dbUser);`