# Promisify trying to connect class with callback

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to connect steam class [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-userinfo) with my Promise library and receive user info as well but its wont work. The library goes with setup method to add API key for further use.

```
const steamuserinfo = require('steam-userinfo');
steamuserinfo.setup('api KEY');
```

and my method to receive user information which responds me with the following error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserInfo' of undefined

and my code for this method:

```
var steamuserinfo = Promise.promisify(steamuserinfo.getUserInfo);

    return steamuserinfo(steamid, function(error, data){
        if(error) return false;
        var response = JSON.stringify(data.response);

        return response;
    })
```

where could be the problem?

**EDIT with answer**

```
var getSteamUserInfo = Promise.promisify(steamuserinfo.getUserInfo.bind(steamuserinfo));

    getSteamUserInfo(steamid, function (error, data) {
        // handle callback
    });
```

Comment: You'll probably have to pass `steamuserinfo` for the context

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32509904/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi i dont get how to use this with my method

Comment: First of all, don't overwrite `steamuserinfo` (you seem to have both `const` and a `var` with the same name in your code, which should alone throw an exception). Do `var getSteamUserInfo = Promise.promisify(steamuserinfo.getUserInfo.bind(steamuserinfo))` or something like that.

Comment: @Bergi yeah thats work :) thanks man